# laravel - return view from controller vs directly from route?

Tags: laravel

I am learning Laravel and know the concept uses MVC design. From what I learn so far, we can specify the route to return a view in `web.php` with something like:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
return view('welcome');
})
```

Of course it isn't advisable and it would be better to pass the view page in a controller like this:

```
Route:: get('/',NameofController@method);
```

So these two ways can return the same result and I have been told the second approach is a better practice but unsure why. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel :: Routes Vs. Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121787/laravel-routes-vs-controller)

Answer (score 2):

The only reason the second is 'better' is because the first route (with the Closure) cannot be cached, so it'll slow down your routing in larger apps.
If you still want to return a view without creating a controller, you can by using the (cachable) `Route::view('/', 'welcome');`

Comment: Certainly a reason but not the only reason.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Nicolas Goosen's answer, The responsibility of web.php file is to manage the application routes. Your business logic should be stated in controllers. That is why it is a good practice to return views from controller as you may need to apply some business logic before returning view.